# dc.geoChoroplethChart UK JSON data is not displaying in page

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, dc.js

I am new to dc.js and struggling to get the dc.geoChoroplethChart chart to display my UK JSON data. Currently the map is completley blank, any help on this would be greatly appreciated;

Comment: Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: Fixed, I used dc.leafletMarkerChart instead.